# From array of semver version numbers to an major/minor object hash in jq, even possible?

Tags: jq

**Input**

```
[
  "8.1.1",
  "7.4.33",
  "7.4.5",
  "8.2.6"
]
```

**Ouput**

```
{
  "7": "7.4.33",
  "7.4": "7.4.33",
  "8": "8.2.6",
  "8.1": "8.1.1",
  "8.2": "8.2.6"
}
```

Ouput is an object where:

- a key equal to the **major** exists (i.e. `8`), value is the **greatest version** for that major
- a key equal to the **major.minor** exists (i.e. `7.4`), value is the **greatest version** for that major/minor

After a lot of trial and error, right now I'm only able to extract the major and reduce to an array. Any help is much appreciated!

```
echo "[\"8.1.1\",\"7.4.33\",\"7.4.5\",\"8.2.6\"]" | jq -n 'reduce input[] as $version ({}; .[($version | split(".")[0])] += [$version])'
```

Which output:

```
{
  "8": [
    "8.1.1",
    "8.2.6"
  ],
  "7": [
    "7.4.33",
    "7.4.5"
  ]
}
```

**EDIT**: just as a referebnce and to avoid ambiguity, for those who can understand PHP, this is a CLI script that do the same:

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

array_shift($argv);
usort($argv, 'version_compare');

echo json_encode(
    array_reduce(
        array_reverse($argv),
        function (array $prev, $version) use($argv) {
            [$major, $minor] = explode('.', $version, 3);
            $majors = array_filter($argv, function ($v) use ($major) {
                return substr($v, 0, 1) === $major;
            });
            $minors = array_filter($argv, function ($v) use ($major, $minor) {
                return substr($v, 0, 3) === "$major.$minor";
            });

            return $prev + [
                $major => end($majors),
                "$major.$minor" => end($minors),
            ];
        },
        []
    ),
    JSON_FORCE_OBJECT
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be something like:

```bash
jq -c '
  map(split(".") | map(tonumber)) | # transform the version number strings
                                    # to arrays of numbers so we can
                                    # sort them.

    sort |  # those arrays of numbers are sorted numerically in effect
            # conveniently achieving a semver sort

    map(map(tostring)) | # convert the numbers in the arrays back to
                         # string so we can manipulate them as such more
                         # easily.
    map({
          (.[0]) : join("."),
          (.[0] + "." + .[1]) : join(".")
        }) | # create a {"x":"x.y.z","x.y":"x.y.z"} object for each of
             # those arrays sorted in ascending version number

    add  # adding those objects means merging them, with the last one
         # for a given key taking precedence.
' file.json
```

But though doing it in `jq` is an interesting exercise in brain twisting, I think I'd go with a generic programming language with a JSON module such as perl/ruby/python to solve this  kind of problem, where the algorithm and code is much easier to come up with and understand and maintain going forward. For example, in `perl`:

```bash
perl -MJSON -MSort::Versions -l -0777 -ne '
  $j = decode_json($_);
  for (sort versioncmp @$j) {
    @p = split/\./;
    $max{$p[0]} = $_;
    $max{"$p[0].$p[1]"} = $_
  }
  print encode_json(\%max)' file.json
```

(those `JSON` and `Sort::Versions` modules may not be installed by default on your system, but then again, `jq` rarely is either).

Or even since here it's only digits and `.`, do it with some basic awk (and GNU `sort` for version sort, and GNU `grep` for the extraction of the version numbers):

```bash
grep -Po '[\d.]+' file.json |
  sort -V |
  awk -F. '
    {
      max[$1] = $0
      max[$1"."$2] = $0
    }
    END {
      printf "{"
      for (i in max) {
        printf c"\"%s\":\"%s\"", i, max[i]
        c = ","
      }
      print "}"
    }'
```